# How to know which value changed after Firebase update?

Tags: javascript, firebase, callback, firebase-realtime-database, promise

Here is my data structure :

```
- data
      key1 : value4
      key3 : value3
```

My code :

```
obj = {key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3}
firebase.database().ref('/data').update(obj)
```

I would like to know if there is a promise or a callback after the update to get only the keys that were modified. Any clues ?

Comment: Which version of Firebase?

Comment: Firebase 4.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

To answer **if there is a promise or a callback after the update**,

Yes there is, it returns a promise,

```
obj = {key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3}
firebase.database().ref('/data').update(obj)
.then(function(data) {
       console.log('Update succeeded');
       //check what data you are getting
       console.log(data);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Update failed');
    console.log(error);
});
```

To answer **update to get only the keys that were modified** - not sure what you mean, you already have the keys that are being updated right??

Comment: This is indeed the general approach. But there is no `data` passed into the promise. See https://jsbin.com/gitobuj/edit?html,js,console. The Firebase API does not expose the delta anyway: it just exposes the new data at the location.

Comment: As Franck Van Puffelen said, I'm looking to get the delta ie just the keys that will be updated. In my example, the key3 will not be updated but I will ask firebase to update it.